# Require nested evaluation within the status line, a render status line function?

Tags: statusline

With regards to this line (full code at the bottom):

```
let savestatus  = "%{&modified ? '%#StatusUnsaved#[+++]%*' : &modifiable ? '[---] ' : '[ R ]'}"
```

If the file is modified, I wish to print `[+++]` with the highlighting face of `StatusUnsaved`.
However with my code, it literally prints `%#StatusUnsaved#}[+++]%*` in the status line instead of just printing `[+++]` with the highlighting face applied.
I have tried nested `%{}` but that generates errors.

From reading the help it explains the statusline is just a stringf in which string `%` substitutions occur. So it's like I need to call a function like `RenderStatusLine('%#StatusUnsaved#}[+++]%*')`, and return that result. I have searched for a function like that but can't find it.

Here is my full status line code:

```
function MyStatusLine()
    let prefix      = '%{expand("%:h")}'   "Show file path head
    let prefix      = prefix . '/'
    let prefix      = prefix . '%#StatusLineNC#'   "Change to StatusLineNC highlighting
    let prefix      = prefix . ' %t '      "filename only no path (Tail)
    let prefix      = prefix . '%*'        "Return to default color StatusLine / StatusLineNC
    let savestatus  = "%{&modified ? '%#StatusUnsaved#[+++]%*' : &modifiable ? '[---] ' : '[ R ]'}"
    let sep         = ' %= '               "Left/Right separator
    let fug         = "%{exists('g:loaded_fugitive') ? fugitive#statusline() : ''}"
    let position    = ' %6l'               "Current line number
    let position    = position . ',%-3c'   "Current column number, left aligned 3 characters wide
    let position    = position . ' %P '    " Percentage through the file
    return prefix.savestatus.sep.fug.position
endfunction
set statusline=%!MyStatusLine()
```

Comment: When using %! the general strategy is to bake the functions into a single string as much as possible instead of using embedded functions

Comment: I think what @Mass is trying to say is that rather than asking the statusline to get evaluated twice, have your function do the check: `let savestatus = &modified ? 'a' : &modifiable ? 'b' : 'c'`—notice how it is not a string, but an expression that evaluates to a string when the function is called

Comment: Thanks @D.BenKnoble, that did the trick! I thought it would result in savestatus getting one value (the first time it is called at initialisation), but it is rev-evaluated every time, great!

Answer (score 2):

<strike>Since `%!` statusline functions are re-evaluated (at what frequency, I do not know), you can do this instead:</strike>

```
let savestatus  = &modified ? '%#StatusUnsaved#[+++]%*' : &modifiable ? '[---] ' : '[ R ]'
```

According to `:help statusline`:

```
    When the option starts with "%!" then it is used as an expression,
    evaluated and the result is used as the option value.  Example: >
        :set statusline=%!MyStatusLine()
<   The *g:statusline_winid* variable will be set to the |window-ID| of the
    window that the status line belongs to.
    The result can contain %{} items that will be evaluated too.
    Note that the "%!" expression is evaluated in the context of the
    current window and buffer, while %{} items are evaluated in the
    context of the window that the statusline belongs to.
```

Therefore, `%{}` *should* be evaluated, so it is bizarre that it is not.

Fundamentally, I believe the problem is the same as if you do this:

```
set statusline=%{&modified?'%1*[+++]%*':&modifiable?'[---]':'[R]'}
```

Because the `%1*` "just some string," it doesn't get evaluated.

---

However, you might be interested in `%m` and `%r` flags (and their capital variants). You'll have less control over the exact text, but they just work, and you can color them how you see fit.

Comment: The only problem is, if I open a help window, then if my other file is modified, it will show the help window as modified too. If I go to the other window and save it, then it changes both the saved and help file windows to not showing modified. I tried `setlocal statusline=%!MyStatusLine()` but then the statusline is just blank.

Comment: Hm... I’ll have to investigate a bit.

Comment: I actually started rewriting my status line config so I can have none default %m and %r flags. Thanks for you help though, helped me get there in the end!

Answer (score 1):

With the help of [D. Ben Knoble](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/10604/d-ben-knoble)

```
hi StatusLine           guifg=#000000 guibg=#00CC00 gui=none " WARNING! By default gui set to reverse, need to overide it with none
hi StatusLineNC         guifg=#192224 guibg=#ABABAB gui=none " Status line None current
hi _StatusFileName      guifg=#FFFFFF guibg=#007700 gui=bold
hi _StatusFileNameNC    guifg=#FFFFFF guibg=#777777 gui=bold
hi _StatusModified      guifg=#FFFFFF guibg=#FF0000 gui=BOLD
hi _StatusGit           guifg=#009900 guibg=#00CC00
hi _StatusGitNC         guifg=#777777 guibg=#ABABAB

function MyStatusLine(currentWindow)
    let s = ""
    let s .= "%{&l:modifiable?expand('%:h').'/':''}"    " Show file path head for modifiable files
    let s .= "%{(&readonly||!&modifiable)?'[R]':''}"    " If readonly file, show [R] instead of filepath
    if a:currentWindow
        let s .= "%#_StatusFileName#"                   " Change to StatusFileName highlighting
    else
        let s .= "%#_StatusFileNameNC#"                 " Change to StatusFileNameNC highlighting
    endif
    let s .= " %t "                                     " filename only no path (Tail)
    let s .= "%*"                                       " Return to default color StatusLine / StatusLineNC
    let s .= "%#_StatusModified#%{&modified?' +++ ':''}%*"
    let s .= " %= "                                     " Left/Right separator
    if exists('g:loaded_fugitive')
        if a:currentWindow
            let s .= "%*%#_StatusGit#%{&l:modifiable ? fugitive#statusline() : ''}%*"
        else
            let s .= "%*%#_StatusGitNC#%{&l:modifiable ? fugitive#statusline() : ''}%*"
        endif
    endif
    let s .= " %6l"                                     " Current line number
    let s .= ",%-3c"                                    " Current column number, left aligned 3 characters wide
    let s .= " %P "                                     " Percentage through the file
    return s
endfunction
"set statusline=%!MyStatusLine('Enter')
autocmd BufWinEnter,WinEnter * setlocal statusline=%!MyStatusLine(1)
autocmd WinLeave * setlocal statusline=%!MyStatusLine(0)
```